# Angular 2 [attr.class] overwrites native DOM classes

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a variable holding my class name string:

```
classNameB = "class-B";
```

I want to add this class name to a native DOM element via `[attr.class]`:

```
<div class="class-A" [attr.class]='classNameB'></div>
```

Then, angular overwrites the current DOM class `class-A`. What has left after element created is something like:

```
<div class="class-B"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong here and how to work around on this?

PS: Can I use `[ngClass]` instead and how?

Comment: You could use `ngClass` directive find it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vDMg1KNxBixUL3E3Vfpp?p=preview)

Comment: @PankajParkar Wow, I don't even know we can use `ngClass` instead of `[ngClass]`. Can you explain what is the different?

Comment: There is no difference. The `[]` is for all attribute and property bindings, not only for `ngClass`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I went through some funny situations where I almost ran out of options. Most of the time, I use `[ngClass]` and it was fine until:

```
<div class='native-class' [ngClass]='classNameHolder' [ngClass]='{"some-class": isSomeClass}'>
```

where,

```
classNameHolder: string = 'class-name-1';
isSomeClass: boolean = true;
```

I was stuck until I find good use of `ngClass`:

```
<div class='native-class' ngClass='{{classNameHolder}} {{isSomeClass ? "some-class" : ""}}></div>
```

And that's it. This is final option that I've been using from then. Hope it'll help if anyone runs into the same sitation.

Answer (score 0):

```
[attr.class]='classNameB'
```

here the classNameB should be $scope attached variable. which can be an expression or value.
you can also modify the code like this

```
[attr.class]='{{getClassName()}}'
```

for ng-class attribute it works same for both.
or you can have a class on boolean basis

```
[attr.class]="'ifThis'?'classNameB':'classNameA'"
```

or

```
 ng-class="varA==0 ?'classNameB':'classNameA'"
```

Comment: Why you are mixing Angular1 with Angular2? `$scope` is there in `A1` where as attribute binding is there in `A2`

Comment: I wonder the same thing. Besides, `[attr.class]='{{getClassName()}}'` doesn't work. It will return error _Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected_

Comment: You can't use `[]` and `{{}}` together. Either `[]` or `{{}}` but not both. `[]` is to assign values as-is, `{{}}` to assign stringified values.

Comment: There also is no `ng-class` in Angular2, it's `ngClass`